# Pointers On Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void F1(void *comp, void *record){
   int complen = strlen((char *)comp), recordlen = *(int *)record;
   *(int *)record = complen>recordlen ? complen : recordlen;
}

void F2(void *comp, void *ans){
   if(!*(char **)ans)
      *(char **)ans = (char *)comp;
   else if(strcmp((char *)comp, *(char **)ans) < 0)
      *(char **)ans = (char *)comp;
}


void ProcessStrings(char ***vals, void* (*fp)(char *, void *), void *champ){
   char **copy = *vals;
   while(*copy){
      fp(*copy++, champ);
   }
}

int main() {
   char *strings1[][100] = {{"beta", "alpha", "gamma", "delta", NULL}, {"Johnson", "Smith", "Smithson", "Zimmerman", "Jones", NULL}, {"Mary", "Bill", "Bob", "Zoe", "Annabelle", "Bobby", "Anna", NULL}};
   int maxLen = 0;
   char *minString = NULL;
   ProcessStrings(strings1, F1, &maxLen);
   ProcessStrings(strings1, F2, &minString);
   printf("Strings1: Max length is %d and min is %s\n", maxLen, minString);
}
```

A quick background...function F1 supplies the max length of a list of strings to it's second parameter. F2 supplies the minimum string in terms of ASCII value.

My error message states that I'm passing an incompatible pointer type to process strings. When I draw out the pointers, I feel as though I am not. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an incompatible pointer type indeed.

`strings1` is a 2D array of pointers to chars. Note, that a 2D array elements in C are laid out sequentially row after row, while the function expects to see a pointer after the first dereference of `strings1` inside the `ProcessStrings`.

If you want you code to work correctly, you need to either pass the following construct to `ProcessStrings`

```
   char **strings2[] = {
      strings1[0],
      strings1[1],
      strings2[2]
   };
```

or to change the the function to work with a pointer to an array of 100 char pointers:

```
void ProcessStrings2(char * (*vals)[100], void (*fp)(void *, void *), void *champ){
```

Btw, your function seems to process only the first row of strings.